# phpmyadmnin cannot login to mysql server

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have mysql installed and running on my computer and set a password for root user.

I can login mysql from the command line by typing `mysql -uroot -p`and typing in my password after that.

However after I installed phpmyadmin on my localhost and try to login to mysql server from there with username being "root" and the same password, an error saying "Cannot log in to the MySQL server". I also have the `config.inc.php` set up but still cannot login?

here is my config.inc.php file:

```
<?php
/*
 * Generated configuration file
 * Generated by: phpMyAdmin 4.5.1 setup script
 * Date: Fri, 20 Nov 2015 15:16:01 +0000
 */

/* Servers configuration */
$i = 0;

/* Server: localhost [1] */
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '123456';

/* End of servers configuration */

$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = '564f3756d3b348.23156040';
$cfg['DefaultLang'] = 'en';
$cfg['ServerDefault'] = 1;
$cfg['UploadDir'] = '';
$cfg['SaveDir'] = '';
?>
```

Any suggestions how i can possibly login?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/34409/unable-to-login-to-phpmyadmin-with-the-root-user

Answer (score 0):

The root user with no password is created with access only on the local host. You need to create a user with access from the host you're trying to connect from.

```
CREATE USER 'zhang'@'yourhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'yourpassword;
```

Comment: I added a password for root user and im running it on my local machine. I created a new user and still couldn't login.

Comment: im new to this. what do you mean by that?

Comment: `CREATE USER 'zhang'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'yourpassword;`

Answer (score 0):

First you need to change your login cridentials in phpmyadmin's *config.inc.php*, and then restart your web and mysql servers.

Go to phpmyadmin installation directory and find file *config.inc.php* and in that file put your current mysql password at line

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root'; //mysql username here
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'password'; //mysql password here
```

Comment: Did you restart your server after making those changes?

Comment: yes i did. i restarted both apache and mysql server

Comment: Change your `auth_type` to `config`, like this, `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';`. This is because your username and password are stored in phpMyAdmin configuration file.

Comment: And don't forget to restart your apache and mysql server.

Comment: it says 'invalid settings' and 'mysql server rejected the connection'

Comment: This is my [config.inc.php](http://pastebin.com/a427Am25) file. You might get some clue from here.